Upgrade python dependencies from Docker file
I need to update python dependencies during boot time. I tried to run a command into Docker file:
RUN pip install --upgrade wheel==0.43.0 setuptools==70.1.0 pip==24.0 
But it's not making a change. What is the proper way to update the packages with the hardcoded versions into Docker file?
Looks like version that I added is not making a change.

You should ensure the commands are correctly formatted and placed appropriately in the Dockerfile.

looks like there's no wheel version 0.43.0 - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel==0.43.0
(same for other two)

Yes there is: https://pypi.org/project/wheel/0.43.0/ . It would be helpful to see some error messages from the OP. I suspect the Python version isn't matching the requested package versions, similar to what @mangusta is seeing.

hm, didn't know that the available package versions depend on python version. in my case it's 2.7.17 fyi

did you test this command directly on computer with the same Python version? Maybe it could show some error message which could explain problem

Python 2.71!?!? I am quite sure pip 24 is not available for Python 2.7. The oldest Python version it is available on is Python 3.7. wheel v0.43.0 requires at least Python 3.8. And setuptools 70.1.0 requires Python 3.8 at least as well.
